# Office Scripts Apply Data Validation to Table Column

Tags: excel, validation, office-scripts

I modified an Office Script to apply list-style data validation. The values are on `Sheet1` and the data table is on `Sheet2`.

I cannot figure out how to apply the validation to every row in a table. I am getting the drop-down in cell `C2` but I would like to have the drop down in every cell in that table column.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the values for data validation.
    let selectedSheet =workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let selectedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let rangeValues = selectedRange.getValues();

    // Convert the values into a comma-delimited string.
    let dataValidationListString = "";
    rangeValues.forEach((rangeValueRow) => {
        rangeValueRow.forEach((value) => {
            dataValidationListString += value + ",";
        });
    });
    // Apply the data validation to the first cell in the selected range.
    let targetCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2").getRange("C2");
    let dataValidation = targetCell.getDataValidation();

    // Set the content of the drop-down list.
    dataValidation.setRule({
        list: {
            inCellDropDown: true,
            source: dataValidationListString
        }
    });
}
```

If I use getTable, it tells me dataValidation doesn't exist on table and if I try to use the range `C:C`, the data validation setrule isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: Are you using an Excel table? If so, what is your table name and what is the name of the header in column C?

Comment: For test purposes, the table name is `Table1` and the column name is `Column3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the values for data validation.
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    let selectedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let rangeValues = selectedRange.getValues();

    // Convert the values into a comma-delimited string.
    let dataValidationListString = "";
    rangeValues.forEach((rangeValueRow) => {
        rangeValueRow.forEach((value) => {
            dataValidationListString += value + ",";
        });
    });

    let tbl = workbook.getTable("Table1")
    // Apply the data validation to the first cell in the selected range.
    // let targetCell = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2").getRange("C2");
    let targetColumn = tbl.getColumn("Column3")
    let dataValidation = targetColumn.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getDataValidation();

    // Set the content of the drop-down list.
    dataValidation.setRule({
        list: {
            inCellDropDown: true,
            source: dataValidationListString
        }
    });
}
```

I added a `tbl` variable to reference the Table1 table. I've added a `targetColumn` variable to reference the Column3. You can then use the `getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal()` method to reference the DataBody range of the table. And from there the rest of your code should work.

Comment: Just before you posted this, I had tried getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal and it was throwing this error: `Line 19: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal')`. I have to do a better job of naming! The sample workbook had another table that did not get deleted, so the table I was working with was `Table2`. I have added notes to all my `let` statements to clue me in to what the errors